# Как добавить динамичное количество строк tr в Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в зависимости от количества имеющих строк в файле - добавлять  в шаблоне?

**main.py:**

```
with open("ping.txt", "r") as file1:
     notavailable = (file1.read())
print(notavailable)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", noavailable=notavailable)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

**index.py:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Главная страница
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Доступность комплекса: </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>{{noavailable}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**notavailable** в консоле выводится построчно, а на странице все в одной строке содержится(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:
**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

with open("ping.txt", "r") as file1:
     notavailable = (file1.read())
print(notavailable)
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", notavailable=notavailable.splitlines())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}
Главная страница
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<table class="table table-striped table-sm">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Доступность комплекса: </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            {% for line in notavailable %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ line }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
{% endblock %}
```

P.s. 
Добавил .splitlines(), когда передаю содержимое файла в render_template(), и for по строкам в index.html.

Comment: Приветствую, Александр! Изначально так и было сделано, что пинговало отдельно, заносило в файл и через терминал я отсматривал информацию, но сейчас появилась потребность именно пинговать и значения заносить в базу данных

Comment: Я не понял то, что ты хочешь, и ответил не на тот вопрос или ты уже сам всё сделал? P.s. Просто из вопроса я не понял про базу данных.

Comment: Ну, думаю ты уже и так загуглил, но есть sqlalchemy и flask_sqlalchemy для работы с бд. Можешь почитать про них.

Comment: Александр, затупил я.. У меня еще вопрос висит, про базу данных) Да, то, как вы написали - сработало! Спасибо!))